# Рассчитать расстояние до линии

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется множество точек, а именно тачей(точки где пользователь провел пальцем) и имеется LineRenderer, также с множеством точек. Как рассчитать расстояние от каждого тача до линии, а не до точек изгиба? Либо посоветуйте другой способ реализовать данную функцию. Основная задача - определить точность проведения линии пользователем. 
[image: Красная линия с острыми углами - LineRenderer. Линия с округлыми изгибами - Множество Тачей пользователя]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Нахождение расстояния от точки до отрезка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438244/how-to-calculate-shortest-2d-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment-in-all)

Пусть есть массив точек `expectedLine`, элементы которого - точки изгиба ломаной.

Для каждой точки touch-линии `touchPoint` находим индекс ближайшей точки ломаной линии, назовем этот индекс `closestIndex`.

Находим минимум из трёх расстояний:

1. Расстояние между точками `touchPoint` и `expectedLine[closestIndex]`
2. Расстояние от точки `touchPoint` до отрезка `[expectedLine[closestIndex]; expectedLine[closestIndex - 1]]`
3. Расстояние от точки `touchPoint` до отрезка `[expectedLine[closestIndex]; expectedLine[closestIndex + 1]]`

Найденный минимум и будет расстоянием до ближайшего отрезка ломаной.

Обратите внимание, что "расстояние от точки до отрезка" отличается от "расстояния от точки до прямой". Например, если опущенный из точки на прямую перпендикуляр  не попадает в отрезок. Это учтено в приведённой ссылке.